# Adding a User to a WordPress Site in Multisite

Tags: mysql, wordpress, multisite

i have a WordPress multisite scenario.
i added the user like so:

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_status, user_registered) VALUES ('$id', '$i', MD5('$pass'), '$i', '$email', '0', '$date');
```

now i want to add the user to a specific site in the multisite.
i do this:

```
insert into wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($userID, 'wp_${siteID}_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";s:1:\"1\";}')"
insert into wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($userID, 'wp_${siteID}_user_level', '7')
insert into wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($userID, 'nickname', '$i')
```

however, when i try to login with this user, i get an error:
"Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

any ideas?

Comment: why cant you add user in wp-admin itself instead of sql commands, and set the role as admin?

Comment: Automation. Adding multiple users

Answer (score 0):

solved.
had to use escape characters, like this:

```
insert into wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($userID, 'wp_${siteID}_capabilities', 'a:3:{s:6:"\""editor"\"";b:1;s:6:"\""author"\"";b:1;s:11:"\""contributor"\"";b:1;}')
```